# Is there anyway on Angular Universal to find where the window reference error is located at?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-universal, angular-ngselect, ngx-quill

So I have an Angular Universal project working fine. After adding quite a lot of code and some external npm libraries such as Quill I am finding now a window Reference error. I have checked all my components and in all of them when I reference window it is wrapped under the `if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){` .

Error message:

```
D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1
!function(e,a){for(var i in a)e[i]=a[i]}(exports,function(modules){var installedModules={},installedChunks={1:0};function __webpack_require__(moduleId){if(installedModules[moduleId])return installedModules[moduleId].exports;var module=installedModules[moduleId]={i:moduleId,l:!1,exports:{}};return modules[moduleId].call(module.exports,module,module.exports,__webpack_require__),module.l=!0,module.exports}return __webpack_require__.e=function requireEnsure(chunkId){if(0!==installedChunks[chunkId]){var chunk=require("./"+({0:"components-socs-society-page-society-page-module"}[chunkId]||chunkId)+".js"),moreModules=chunk.modules,chunkIds=chunk.ids;for(var moduleId in moreModules)modules[moduleId]=moreModules[moduleId];for(var i=0;i<chunkIds.length;i++)installedChunks[chunkIds[i]]=0}return Promise.all([])},__webpack_require__.m=modules,__webpack_require__.c=installedModules,__webpack_require__.d=function(exports,name,getter){__webpack_require__.o(exports,name)||

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.ah1v (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:991591)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:317)
    at Module.uj+Y (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:3975408)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:317)
    at Object.0 (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:6384)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:317)
    at +iJU (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:2122)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PROYECTO SOCIAL\FRONT\dist\front\server\main.js:1:2167)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! front@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/front/server/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the front@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
```

Is there anyway I could check where this error is located at to determine which library or code file is causing it?

Comment: Open the `main.js` file with a text editor and try to see where is the code from. If you build the server without optimisation, the code will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

So FYI for those inexperienced with this it seems that the core problem was related to ngx Quill and adding external modules to it such as BlotFormatter or the emoji module. [Here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/91) is a discussion regarding this.

Also, as @David mentioned you can get more context of the error by accessing `main.js` file within `dist/yourappname/server/main.js`. If you are using VS Code you can easily jump into the faulty line of code by using `Ctrl + G` and writing the line of code shown in the error message.